# How to change the form of GCBV?

Tags: django, django-forms

I have GCBV

```
@method_decorator(login_required, name='dispatch')
class PostUpdateView(UpdateView):
    model = Post
    fields = ('message', )
    template_name = 'edit_post.html'
    pk_url_kwarg = 'post_pk'
    context_object_name = 'post'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(PostUpdateView, self).get_queryset()
        return queryset.filter(created_by=self.request.user)

    def form_valid(self, form):
        post = form.save(commit=False)
        post.updated_by = self.request.user
        post.updated_at = timezone.now()
        post.save()
        return redirect('topic_posts', pk=post.topic.board.pk, topic_pk=post.topic.pk)
```

I need to add pagedown widget to the form, where cad I add it?
I know how to do it with FBV but with GCBV we dont define the form which we need, How can I define and change it?

Comment: So, *do* define the form and reference it in the `form_class` attribute.

Comment: Where is attribute of form_class?